# Is this a opinion-based question?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Economics Stack Exchange post: [What happen if USA print trillions of(almost unlimited) of money?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/47713/what-happen-if-usa-print-trillions-ofalmost-unlimited-of-money)

This question has been closed as an opinion-based question, but I don't feel that it will be an opinion-based question. I think it should have an economic-based answer.

**Note: Please note that I am not an economics expert, I am just a software engineer who loves to learn about economics.**

Answer (score 3):

The question is opinion based as nobody can give you realistic forecast to what will happen to the world economy under some completely unrealistic scenario.

Question that cannot be answered with some published research/work/textbook as a reference or with reference to real world data, will necessarily require people to state opinions.

In addition, people can choose only one reason for closing question, but your question could be also closed as:

- too broad: on this site we do not allow questions that are too broad. Questions should be narrow about some specific problem.
- needs details and clarity: scenario in your question is extremely vague. What even counts as almost unlimited amount of money? what time frame we are even talking about? etc

Chatty questions, that can't be answered by facts and research, questions are too broad or vague are considered off topic on this site. See more details in our [help center](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help).